# Returning result of a different route, without redirecting

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to do something like this:
When a new request for /givemeissues comes, it should return the result of /issues route.

```
def api_request(url, data=False, req_type="GET", params={}):
    json_file = json.dumps(data)
    headers = {
        'content-type': "application/json",
    }
    response = requests.request(req_type, url, data=json_file, headers=headers, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if request.url.split('/')[-1] == 'givemeissues':
        return api_request('http://127.0.0.1/issues', data=False, req_type="GET")
```

The reason is, I have some old urls (out on the internet), and I want to map them to new routes (mapping is stored in my db), but I do not want to redirect.

The above code does not work. The request never completed for some reason.

Comment: What does the api_request function do?

Comment: Added to the Question Description just now.

Comment: What was the problem with your code?

Comment: The code does not work. The request never completed for some reason.

Comment: Try adding an else in case the response code is not 200 and put a print in it or some other return message. It might be possible that the request didn't work for some reason

Comment: I tried that, but what is happening is, this line ' response = requests.request(req_type, url, data=json_file, headers=headers, params=params)' in api_request method never completes execution. It never even reaches the before_request method again.

Comment: Could it be because python server cannot serve another request until first is complete??